# Angular2 Template Reference Variables and dynamic updating

Tags: angular

I was originally trying to set up a template reference variable in Angular2 so I could reverse the sort order of a table without having to do the binding but I wasn't getting the dynamic updating of the interface when I was clicking the checkbox.  I created a simple plunker in case I had something else in my app that might have been messing with the code and I don't see the interpolated value of the reference being updated on the fly.  I made it a textbox to see if the value would change as I typed.  It doesn't appear to be updating.

Am I missing something in my setup to make this work?  Or am I trying to use the reference variables in a way they weren't created to be used for?

http://plnkr.co/edit/BK4MzU8KTvEyXDxTNHSR?p=preview

```javascript
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2> 
       <input #myInput type="text" value="yeh" /> The INPUT value is "{{myInput.value}}"
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `<input #myInput type="text" value="yeh" />` you create a local template reference to DOM element, however it doesn't mean Angular watches it's value or any other arbitrary property, like `checked`, etc.

If you need to watch value you should better use ngModel or ngControl (see another answer (which is deleted now: `<input [(ngModel)]="myInput" type="text" value="yeh" />`)).

Another solution is to trigger "watching" by subscribing to some of the input events, e.g. keyup or input.

```html
<input #myInput type="text" (input)="false" value="yeh" /> {{ myInput.value }}
```

and use some "event handler" or fake one, like `false`. As you can see this is really weird, avoid it.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/JIwPDPyYFnkDtz99sew3?p=info

Comment: I figured this might be the case but wasn't 100% sure of exactly how the reference was supposed to work here.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<input #myInput type="text" value="yeh" (keyup)="myInput.value" /> The INPUT value is "{{myInput.value}}"
```

See if this helps.