# Angular, Reference variable does not refresh

Tags: angular

I don't want to user a variable in the component, only user reference variables in HTML. Here is the code:

```
<fieldset id="group1">
  <input type="radio" value="value1" name="group1" [checked]="true" #list>List
  <input type="radio" value="value2" name="group1" #map>Map
</fieldset>
{{list.checked}}
```

When I launched the code, list.checked = return true.
When I click on the second radio button, list.checked is supposed to now return false but it's not the case.

How to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkaa6s) You need to use value bind and give true false to them. Then with ngModel two way binding you assign it to variable. In component initialize it as true.

```
<fieldset id="group1">
  <input type="radio" value="value1" name="group1"[(ngModel)]="data" [value]="true" #list>List
  <input type="radio" value="value2" name="group1"[(ngModel)]="data"[value]="false" #map>Map
</fieldset>
{{list.checked}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this question + answer explains why Angular acts this way [Angular2 Template Reference Variables and dynamic updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335717/angular2-template-reference-variables-and-dynamic-updating))

In short he says:
With `<input #myInput type="text" value="yeh" />` you create a local template reference to DOM element, however it doesn't mean Angular watches it's value or any other arbitrary property, like checked, etc.

So that's why the answer above from pc_coder works because ngModel forces Angular to watch the html element.